# Solo se ejecuta el IF de mi cadena de control "if" else if"

Tags: php, ajax

Ya probe todas las condiciones y todas se ejecutan de manera normal, el problema viene es cuando lo maneja con esta cadena de control, es como que no entrara al else if. estoy insertando info de un formulario con unas fotos, y estoy imprimiendo poco a poco lo que me manda ajax.
Hay algo que este haciendo mal en la cadena de control?.
O sera que esta devolviendo puro fals o true y no lo reconoce mi cadena. Imprimi con REQUEST, y si me imprime lo que trae.

He aqui mi codigo

```
    <?php

      if (isset($_POST['numero_dni'])) {
       $nroDocumento = $_POST['numero_dni'];
        print_r($nroDocumento);
     } else if (isset($_FILES['fotodocfront']) && ($_FILES['fotodocpost'])) {
      $fotodocumentofront = $_FILES['fotodocfront']['tmp_name'];
      $fotodocumentoPost = $_FILES['fotodocpost']['tmp_name'];
      cargarImagenesDocYMono($fotodocumentofront, $fotodocumentoPost);
     }

        function cargarImagenesDocYMono($fotodocumentofront, $fotodocumentopost)
   {

// Primera imagen front

$id = '123456';
$type = 'jpg';


$fotodocumentofront = $_FILES['fotodocfront']['tmp_name'];

$nameuno = $id . 'front.' . $type;

if (is_uploaded_file($fotodocumentofront)) {

    $destinouno = '../../estilos/imagenes/imgRegister/' . $nameuno;

    $nombresuno = $nameuno;
    copy($fotodocumentofront, $destinouno);
}

// Segunda imagen front


$fotodocumentopost = $_FILES['fotodocpost']['tmp_name'];

$namedos = $id . 'post.' . $type;

if (is_uploaded_file($fotodocumentopost)) {

    $destinodos = '../../estilos/imagenes/imgRegister/' . $namedos;

    $nombresdos = $namedos;
    copy($fotodocumentopost, $destinodos);
}

// Segunda imagen front

if (isset($_FILES['infomono']['tmp_name'])) {

    $fotomonotributo = $_FILES['infomono']['tmp_name'];

    $nametres = $id . 'mono.' . $type;

    if (is_uploaded_file($fotomonotributo)) {

        $destinotres = '../../estilos/imagenes/imgRegister/' . $nametres;

        $nombresuno = $nametres;
        copy($fotomonotributo, $destinotres);
       }
    }
}
```

y esto es lo que llega desde mi ajax. que ya comprobe que todo llega, pq ya inserte imagenes, ya recibi lo que envia por POST y lo imprimi, pero es como que no lo reconoce.

```
         $("#datosPost").submit(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();


      const datos = new FormData();


  datos.append("fotodocfront",documentoFront);
  datos.append("fotodocpost",documentoPost);
  datos.append("infomono",monotributo);
 datos.append("numero_dni", $("#numero_dni").val());

  $.ajax({
   url: "../../model/work/prueba.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: datos,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success: function (response){
    console.log(response);
 
    }

   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien lo que has dicho, tu problema es que tienes un `if`, y luego un `else if`. Si entra al primer `if`, nunca va a entrar al segundo `else if`, ya que solo entrará si no ha podido entrar al primero (Eso significa el **else**).

Si quieres que pueda entrar a ambos, tienes que hacerlo así:

```
//Primer if aquí
//Dado que en tu petición siempre incluyes el campo 'numero_dni' lo suyo sería comprobar
//que además de existir, no esté vacío, ya que en principio siempre estará ahí
if(isset($_POST['numero_dni']) && !empty($_POST['numero_dni'])){
    $nroDocumento = $_POST['numero_dni'];
    print_r($nroDocumento);
}
//Segundo if aquí, sin else. Al añadir un else haces que eliga uno u otro, nunca ambos.
if(isset($_FILES['fotodocfront']) && ($_FILES['fotodocpost'])) {
    $fotodocumentofront = $_FILES['fotodocfront']['tmp_name'];
    $fotodocumentoPost = $_FILES['fotodocpost']['tmp_name'];
    cargarImagenesDocYMono($fotodocumentofront, $fotodocumentoPost);
}
//Resto del código aquí
```

Te pongo un ejemplo para que lo veas en javascript (el else if funciona igual en todos los lenguajes que lo tienen, da igual php o javascript)

```js
let x = 1;
let y = 1;
console.log("Probamos con else if");
//Usando else if solo entrará al primero
if(x == 1){
    console.log("Solo imprimirá x == 1");
}else if(y == 1){
    console.log("y == 1 también es cierto, pero no saldrá porque ya ha entrado al if de arriba");
}
console.log("Ahora probamos con el if sin else");

//Usando solo if entrará en ambos
if(x == 1){
    console.log("En el if x == 1 entra");
}
if(y == 1){
    console.log("Y aquí también imprimirá y == 1");
}
```

Eso es porque usar `else if` es equivalente a escribir:

```
if(loquesea){
//haz algo
}else{
    if(loquesea2){
    //Haz otra cosa
    }
}
```

Simplemente, te permite ahorrarte un par de corchetes al escribirlo junto.

Comment: entiendo, entoncs me sugieres que compruebe todo en un if si viene del ajax? y que ejecute ciertas funciones

Comment: Puedes comprobarlo en varios `if` separados, pero si usas un else, el código entrará solo al *primer* if válido, ignorando los demás

Comment: gracias benito.!

Comment: Como añadido, tu comprobacion en el PHP es un ISSET. Lo más probable es que lo que quieras es utilizar un !EMPTY (ya que el hecho de que este definido ese índice es siempre, pero el que tenga un valor o no es cuando has enviado un valor por el formulario.

Comment: Efectivamente, @Jakala, sería más correcto un `!empty`.